# Apply same style to multiple CSS attribute selector

Tags: css, input

How can I apply the style below to a `type="submit"` at the same time? Without duplicating the entire block?

```css
input[type="button"] {
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a comma(`,`) just like this:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
width: 120px;
margin-left: 35px;
display: block;
}
```

check more info [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/f/comma-in-css-selectors.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `,`:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a block of styles to multiple selectors by separating the selectors with commas, as follows:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 35px; 
  display: block;
}
```